# Details of the origin of the term "מושך ערלתו"

Tags: halacha-theory, brit-milah

Without going into much detail, the idea is totally inapplicable in our Halachic reality because we cut the ערלה completely. I understood that in rabbinic times where the term originated, that wasn't the case, and because circumcision was very partial, there was a practice to pull it back in order to lengthen.

Here's one source (Sanhedrin 38b): "רבי יצחק אמר מושך בערלתו היה..."

Is it true that the term stems from the early practice to cut the ערלה incompletely?